# PhantonJS / Selenium Custom UserAgent Issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Reading up on PhantomJS and the other headless browsers i saw it was possible to set a user agent, my basic code:

```
  var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
  driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = false;
  driverService.LoadImages = true;
  driverService.ProxyType = "none";
  var options = new PhantomJSOptions();             
  options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10");
  IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);

  using (var phantomDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService))
  {
   // use code here...
  }
```

My problem is, here:

```
new PhantomJSDriver(driverService))
```

I'm setting up the CreateDefaultService to use, i'm not sure how i would add the:

```
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
```

to be used? or is that executed as is, meaning i don't need to feed the: **driver** variable anywhere in the code, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the options and service together

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = false;
driverService.LoadImages = true;
driverService.ProxyType = "none";

var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10");

using (var phantomDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService, options))
{
    // use code here...
}
```